# How to access root folder?

Tags: nautilus, permissions, root, directory, gksu

I just did a data recovery of a very important file, and it is saved in root folder automatically, and I can't access the root folder even from

```
gksu nautilus
```

it gives this dialog:

```
You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “root”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and verify the root directory is readible.

The output of "ls /" should give you this for the root directory:

```
drwx------  15 root     root    4096 Apr 19 11:35 root
```

You can set the proper permissions with:

```
sudo chmod 0700 /root
```